# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} $ is between $\log(n)$ and $\log(n)+1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The lower bound is pretty simple, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} >\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x}dx = \log(n)$. Could I please ask for pointers for the upper bound?

Comment: $$\frac1{k+1}<\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dx}x<\frac1k$$ And $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's help. I think I solved it and am posting an answer for completeness.

$\frac{1}{k+1}<\int^{k+1}_{k}\frac{1}{x}dx \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}<\int^{n+1}_{1}\frac{1}{x}dx \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1} < \log(n+1)$

Thus, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1} + 1< \log(n+1) + 1$.

Let $m=n+1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k} < \log(m) + 1$.